# How to retrieve a BLOB record from table as bytes using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a binary file which I have inserted into a blob column in a table. Now, I want to retrieve this file as a `bytes` object. But I am getting it as a `tuple`.

**What I have tried so far:**
I am trying to retrieve the file from this blob column with the query below: as explained in the cx_Oracle documentation https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes

```py
def output_type_handler(cursor, name, default_type, size, precision, scale):
    if default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_BLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_LONG_RAW, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

connection.outputtypehandler = output_type_handler
cur.execute('''select blobcol from table''')
data = cur.fetchone()
```

Now, if I do a `type(data)`, I am getting it as a tuple and not as `bytes`.

How do I retrieve the blob object as `bytes` and not a tuple?

Comment: I was able to access the bytes content by making data[0]

Answer (score 1):

The byte object can be accessed within the tuple as data[0]

Comment: In the simple example given, another solution is to use `data, = cur.fetchone()`.  With this, the variable `data` will have the value.